# DotNet Core HttpClient doesn't respect proxy settings on Mac

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have following code which works fine when running on Mac without proxy configured.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);

        string baseUrl = "http://www.bbc.com";

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage res = client.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result;
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

If I configure a proxy for this Mac, the request is not routed through the proxy. If I enter the URL on the Safari browser, It gets routed through the proxy as expected. Is there any setting I have misconfigured? Or is this scenario not supported in DotNet Core? This causes our app fail on a corporate network behind a proxy. Any workaround is also appreciated.

Comment: Answered here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28780

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requoting wfurt's answer at github.

"curl library we use under the cover does not know how to read system settings.
Future work is tracked in [#26593](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26593)"

Workaround:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:3128
export https_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:3128
```

If the proxy server requires a user name and password, include the credentials: `https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.com`

If the proxy server uses a port other than 80, include the port number: `https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080`

If the proxy server is a SOCKS5 proxy, specify the SOCKS5 protocol in the URL: `https_proxy=socks5://socks_proxy.example.com`

Reference: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/http-proxy.html